# How to display success message after php script execution on form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So I guess the title says it all, I've got a little php script hooked up to a single input form. All I want is a success page with a link back shown to the user after they submit their email. This should be easy however I'm very new to php.

Anyway, here's the php and html code:

```
 <?php

  $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];

  $email_from = "LightDesigns";
  $email_subject = "Newsletter group";
  $email_body = "You have received a new person to add to the newsletter: 
  $visitor_email.\n".

  $to = "stefanvujic576@gmail.com";
  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
 ?>


 <section id="newsletter" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Subscribe To My Newsletter</h1>

    <form action="email.php" method="POST" name="newsletterForm">
      <input class="emailBox_1" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email..." 
      name="email">
      <button class="button_1" type="submit" class="button_1">
      <span>Subscribe</span></button>
    </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: I believe you can just make a new html document, your success page, and then use something like http://www.andrewdavidson.com/convert-html-to-php/ to echo the entire thing after your mail(); line (copy your success html into it then copy the echo code into your php).

Comment: After mail command, issue a redirect by using the header command. This does two things for you: it allows a custom success page and prevents double submits if user hits the back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the mail() result and add an IF statement to your view. Also, use isset() so the mail is not triggered on page opening and only on email submission.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['email'])){
      $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];

      $email_from = "LightDesigns";
      $email_subject = "Newsletter group";
      $email_body = "You have received a new person to add to the newsletter: 
      $visitor_email.\n".

      $to = "stefanvujic576@gmail.com";
      $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
      $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
      $result = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
      // if ($result){
      // Redirect to success
      // header("location:success.php");
      // exit();
      // }
    }
?>


 <section id="newsletter" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Subscribe To My Newsletter</h1>
    <?php
    if ($result){
        // Inline success
        echo "Success";
        // or
        // Include success
        // include("success.php");
        // or
        // redirect to success
        // echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL='success.php'\" />";  
    }else{
        ?>
            <form action="email.php" method="POST" name="newsletterForm">
              <input class="emailBox_1" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email..." 
              name="email">
              <button class="button_1" type="submit" class="button_1">
              <span>Subscribe</span></button>
            </form>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
 </div>
```

Instead of emailing you the email to add, why not just add it to the DB?

Comment: Thanks, this works very well, although, how can I specify an html page to display when the form processes. I guess my question is: how can I reference a html page in the if statement instead of just echoing success? Sorry for being a pain.

Comment: No problem. I edited my script with a few sugestions

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer ;-). If you use the header() relocation, make sure you don't have any HTML outputted before the redirect or it will make a header already sent error

Comment: You can also use .html in the include() function. (just saying)

Comment: Thank's Patrick. When I click the arrow, it says the answer is recorded and will be accepted when I reach the minimum number of rep points. Seems like I don't have enough rep points right now.

Comment: lol no problem. Pay back the help to an other visitor when you have the time. That's how SO works ;-)

Comment: wow looks like you got the rep ;-) Have a great day and happy coding!